# Use Java TCP to send character by character to server

Tags: java, tcp, client, telnet

I am attempting to send one character at a time to a server using a Java client.

But packets are being grouped even though I disabling Nagle's algorithm.

s.setTcpNoDelay(true);

Any solutions?

Comment: what do you mean being grouped? The data arrives in fragments?

Comment: You cannot warrant they will come in the other side exactly one by one, the receiver's network driver can group data received even if they are in different packets. A better approach is to parse the received data byte by byte and assume you cannot control how much bytes you will receive

Comment: What I mean is that if I send "test" letter by letter (one packet per letter), the letters are combined into one packet and the text is received as "test" rather than "t","e","s","t". This is not supposed to happen if Nagle's algorithm is disabled but it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Tcp connections guarantee you that the data will arrive in the order that you sent it. It does not guarantee that it will all arrive in one packet. It depends on the network and the size of the Tcp packet. So your data can arrive in fragments. The best approach is to use parse the data and let the receiver determine if the packet is complete.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not designed to give you control over how much data is in a packet, and as Gusman said, even if you manage to craft your TCP packets like that, the recipient's kernel is allowed to merge your packets together or split them up. TCP is designed to give you a continuous stream of characters (as opposed to UDP, which lets you specify which data should go into one packet).

However, I doubt that you want to use UDP. Judging from your question, what you really want is a way to delimit messages that are sent over TCP. If every message you send is one line, you could e.g. try ending messages with a newline, then on the other side, read until you get a newline. If you're sending binary data, the usual approach is to send the length of the data before the actual data so that the recipient knows how much he has to send.

If you really need to craft TCP packets like that, e.g. for an attack, you should write your code in C or so and use low-level interfaces of your operating system that let you craft your own IP packets with arbitrary headers and implement TCP yourself.